# Cannot scroll downwards, cannot select and scroll downwards for all browsers, cannot scroll down dota

Tags: 16.04, mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

), I noticed i cannot select text and scroll down in any browser (not just chrome - from other Ubuntu questions) but scrolling up is fine. This same thing occurs during DOTA, where moving the mouse top /left/right scrolls, but bottom is unable to scroll.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Tried: FIrefox, chrome. Even webstorm the IDE scrolling down is impossible while selecting text or very very slow.

EDIT: DOTA scroll works correctly on full screen, suspect its a unity /gnome issue

Comment: I don't know what DOTA is, but to select text outside of the visible window you just have to drag the mouse pointer down below the window, you do not need to manually scroll.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Its a game, on full screen it works correctly (updated answer). Yes, the mouse pointer down the window is not working, neither is selecting and dragging text downwards, that is my question :)

Comment: I guess that you have to provide many more informations, like at least what browser at what version. Here with Ubuntu 14.04,unity and the browser chrome it works without problems :)

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify more. I tried both chrome and firefox, even some IDE's cannot let me scroll. I dont think its a browser problem,but a unity / gnome problem

Comment: I have the same issue with `chromium 53.0.2785.143` . This bug report suggests it's crossplatform issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79551